# Can snow fall on half-steps?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently made a path across a snowy field using cobblestone, and when it snowed, my cobblestone path was buried, requiring me to perform the tedious task of shoveling out the snow. In order to not be doing chores in Minecraft that I'm oft too lazy to do in real life, I was thinking about using half-steps for the path.

#### Is it possible for snow to stick to half-steps in Minecraft? What about double half-steps?

Edit to add:

Are there any solid blocks that snow cannot stick to?

<sub>For reference purposes, assume Minecraft Beta version 1.6.6</sub>

Comment: I've added a third pseudo-question, I hope it's considered relevant enough to this question. If not, I will remove it and create a separate question for it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not possible for snow to exist on slabs/half steps. A slab is only ½ blocks high, but as far as the game is concerned, it inhabits an entire block. The same goes for the snow layer, which is also a block — except other blocks you place can go through and replace the snow layer block. So snow on a slab would have to float half a block above ground.

Try placing a cobblestone block on a slab, same thing:

[image: Cobblestone on Stone Slab]

Double slabs are a different block entirely. Their height is exactly one block, so snow can exist/will fall on it.

> Edit to add:
>
> Are there any solid blocks that snow cannot stick to?

Those would be non-opaque blocks: Glass and ice. In Fancy Graphics mode, snow will also not fall on leaves.

Comment: Actually, I think that Notch fixed the bug leaves always being opaque in smp with v1.6.

Comment: @Ullallulloo Seems that way! I did some testing on a server, but it was Bukkit so I could play around with the weather. Apparently Bukkit still has some issues with the leaves and graphics mode.

Comment: Yeah, I think snow on leaves depends if you're running regular or fast graphics.  Not sure how it works in SMP, it may depend on the client side, and you just see the snow or don't.

Comment: @turkeyandcheese So it does... they haven't quite fixed that yet, then.

Answer (score 5):

I just tested this with a snow golem in 1.5.2 (right before the horse update)

Snow was placed on glass, glowstone, gravel, sand, and end stone just fine.

However, upside down stone slab and upside down nether brick slab did not work, even though their top is flush with a normal full sized block.

Answer (score 1):

You can hack snow in, and it will 'float' above halfsteps.

It will not fall naturally.

Comment: Fairly sure snow has been re-added.