# Does snow falling on a transparent block allow it to start spawning mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm building an extremely long elevated boatway and am trying to figure out what blocks I could use to hold in the water/guide the boat without needing to light them. My boatway, however, passes through quite a few snow biomes. I know that snow won't collect on glass, but since glass is labor intensive I was hoping to use cobble slabs. Can snow accumulate on slabs or any other transparent blocks? If so, will they then be able to spawn mobs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Snow can't fall on slabs, and therefore, won't spawn mobs (as stated in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24084/can-snow-fall-on-half-steps)). Additionally, the [Minecraft Wiki article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Snow_%28cover%29) for Snow states it can't fall on Ice or Glass. Therefore, they won't be able to spawn mobs either.