# How can I prevent snow from sticking around in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit, minecraft-technic-pack

The spawnpoint of my Tekkit Lite server is a massive ice plains biome for hundreds of blocks. In order to make it a bit more hospitable, I'm wanting to somehow get rid of the snow near the spawn.

So far, it seems like the options are:

- Make the ground all slabs [like so](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24084/can-snow-fall-on-half-steps).
- Put a big glass ceiling over everything.

Are there any other options? What's the least intrusive way (i.e. the way that prevents me from having to build some kind of canopy)?

***Note**: I'm the server admin and I'm also okay with using hacks to accomplish this, if any exist. Though I would rather do things in-game if possible.*

Comment: Do torches still melt snow?

Comment: Yep! It's like a 5x5 shape. Bit of effort to cover everything with them, though.

Answer (score 6):

Since you said you're the admin, and you don't mind using hacks, you could move the spawn point.  In a similar vein, you could set the biome to be something different.  For vanilla, the easiest way I know to accomplish these tasks is to use an editor such as [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/).  Both tasks are relatively straight forward, however I don't know the steps required off hand.

Having said that, it's hard to tell if MCEdit (in particular) will work with your world.  It appears that it's hit or miss with some mods, and even different versions of the same mod, especially if those mods introduce naturally generating blocks (or if your world already contains non-vanilla blocks).  Back up your world before attempting.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. I should have mentioned, I do like the spawn point as it exists, and I like the challenge it gives players when starting out (Finding rubber trees takes awhile, for instance). Plus we have a bunch of stuff built there already. Really, I'm just wanting to make a chunk or two less snowy.

Comment: So setting the biome will do this.  It'll change the colour of the grass, but it'll also prevent snow from falling.  Depending on the biome you choose, you could end up with having rain instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you like the biome the way it is, but you just want to prevent snow, get the plugin World Edit. There is a feature that allows you to turn off weather in a certain area, and therefore prevent snow. If this feature doesn't exist anymore (which is possible considering I haven't owned a server or been admin for over a year) there is a simple way of making a canopy.

Comment: Interesting -- I've kind of discounted getting WorldEdit to work because it's a Bukkit plugin and I haven't bothered with BukkitForge yet (Which is needed to get Bukkit stuff working on Tekkit Lite, AFAIK). Thanks!

Comment: No problem, let me know if you do decide to go through with it, and how it ends out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/give (YourName) barrier`

Barrier blocks are completely invisible full blocks. Build a ceiling out of them.

Answer (score 0):

use worldguard and select terrain that you don't want the snow to form make the region and set flag snowForms to deny.

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade! While this answer *should* work, can you provide some detailed step by step instructions with a screenshot or two perhaps?